# Embed PDF while Removing Print / Save / Etc. .

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, embed

I'm trying to allow the user to view a PDF from a webpage, but disable them to download or print said PDF. I keep running into problems with flash or chromes built in PDF viewer. I've tried Iframe, normal embed, PDF security, adobeJS or w/e it's called but no luck.

Anybody have a universal suggestion on how I can get this to work?

Comment: There is no way to get this done IMHO. As soon as your PDF file is loaded in memory in some computer outthere, you lost. You cannot view a PDF without downloading it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 8+ hours of trying many different approaches to the problem we ended up going with a paid option of [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) which works in all browsers and looks decent enough for us to use. That is our solution.

Answer (score 2):

1a. You can not send content to a user that they won't be able to print, or save... The closest you can come, would be to show the equivalent content in Flash, and then they can only print the "visible" portion in the flash viewer.

1b. If it goes over the wire, it can be captured.

1. What are you using to generate the PDFs?  You should be able to do a "write-only" PDF, and YMMV even on that.